# Email to Array VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

The code below works perfectly for what I need except I want the `.To` to pull in an array on a specific worksheet "Email List" starting in "A1". Everything I add or subtract from this codes just causes the code to stop. Any help is truly appreciated.

```
    Dim AWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim Sendrng As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    On Error GoTo StopMacro

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With
    Set Sendrng = Worksheets("Daily Notes").Range("A1:M67")            
    Set AWorksheet = ActiveSheet    
    With Sendrng    
        .Parent.Select    
    Set rng = ActiveCell    
        .Select    
        ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
        With .Parent.MailEnvelope
            .Introduction = "Daily Notes *ad items are in bold*"    
            With .Item
                .To = ""
                .CC = ""
                .BCC = ""
                .Subject = "Daily Notes"
                .Send
            End With    
        End With
        rng.Select
    End With
    AWorksheet.Select    
StopMacro:
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = False    
End Sub
```

Comment: "Everything I add or subtract from this codes just causes the code to stop." - what exactly are you adding or substracting?

Comment: Trying different configurations to find a solution - haven't been able to so far.

Answer (score 0):

So, if you rephrase your question, it is something like:

*How to get the values in a range from Excel to a string, separated by ";"?*

Let's suppose that your values are in range "A1:D1". Then, if you introduce the following function:

```
Public Function GetArrayToString(myRange As Range) As String

    Dim cnt     As Range

    For Each cnt In myRange
        GetArrayToString = GetArrayToString & cnt & ";"
    Next cnt

End Function
```

You will get the values like `value1; value2; value3; value4`. This is how to refer it in your code:

`.To = GetArrayToString(Worksheets("TheSpecialOneAkaMrM").Range("A1:D1"))`

Comment: Thank you - I'm not getting that to work with my code but I understand the concept you're trying to explain. Thank you for taking the time to try and help me - it is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: @ValerieHeimkreiter -  "I'm not getting that to work with my code" - why?

Comment: When adding your suggestion it's coming back on undefined. I'm honestly unsure at this point if I'm just missing something because I've been arguing with this for the last 24 hours or what.

Comment: @ValerieHeimkreiter - How exactly are you adding my suggestion? I suppose that you change the name of the worksheet and the range to your own. E.g., `TheSpecialOneAkaMrM` and `A1:D1`?

Comment: Correct. I added it to .To

Comment: Could you copy and paste into my current code so I ensure I'm getting things in the right area. I'm extremely frustrated with myself and this project and do appreciate you help.

Comment: @ValerieHeimkreiter -  https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7d811f2c2a83ad4d5ba5b806c7888a1f

Comment: Thank you!! I think it's working now - truly appreciate the assist!!

Comment: @ValerieHeimkreiter - congrats! Feel free to mark the answer as "Accepted" - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work